# Pcap.Net BadImageFormatException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, pcap.net

Hello I'm new in using PCAP.net and I'm having this error.

[image]

Comment: You are probably even new to .NET. As Pcap.Net relies on a native library, you need to make sure your project's bitness (x86, or x64) matches the bitness of your references.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. Sounds like you just need to set the Platform Target to x86 instead of Any CPU. http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/514869